# Toolbar overflow menu sometimes aligned to left side of screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-toolbar

My app has multiple Fragments and a custom Toolbar, on the MainActivity. The toolbar is inflated on my 1st fragment but not the other fragments. This has worked fine for months. But very recently the pop-up overflow menu has intermittently appeared aligned to the left side of the screen on occasion, instead of the right side:

[image]

Whereas most of the time, it appears exactly where it should:

[image]

Recent changes to my app include a `getActivity.recreate()` when returning from another Activity to MainActivity. There is also a `getActivity.recreate()` called after the result of a button press has been returned. Not very elegant, but the views in the Fragments all depend on the results of these and it's easier to recreate the lot as it doesn't happen very often.

Could it be that my overflow menu has become disconnected from the tool bar between button presses and the MainActivity being destroyed and recreated?

I'm not sure where to place a check for `getActivity == null` and `getActivity.isDestroyed` in relation to when the overflow menu appears - if this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

At the very beginning of my `OnMenuItemClickListener`, I had been checking that `getActivity()` was `!= null`, `!isFinishing()` or `!isDestroyed()` before proceeding with checking which menuItem had been clicked. However, I was not checking that my ViewGroup that the Fragment layout had been inflated to was `null`. Adding a null check for this has made the problem disappear.